# Custom guard that returns a JSX.Element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement a simple "guard" that redirects me to other components given the value of `currentUser` and `currentClub`  :

```
export const ClubDashboard: React.FC = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const currentUser = useStoreState(state => state.currentUser.value);
  const currentClub = useStoreState(state => state.currentClub.value);
  return clubGuard(
    currentUser,
    currentClub,
    <div className="container vertical full-height-screen">
      <Link to={`/clubs/${currentClub!.id}/settings`}>
        <IoIosSettings className="icon absolute-top-right" />
      </Link>
      [...]
    </div>
    id);
}
```

Here is how I implement the function:

```
export const clubGuard = (
  currentUser: User | null,
  currentClub: Club | null,
  page: JSX.Element,
  urlClubId?: string | null,
  pageLoading?: boolean
): JSX.Element => {
  if (!currentUser) {
    return <Redirect to={"/login"} />;
  }
  if (!currentClub || (currentClub && currentClub.id !== urlClubId)) {
    return <Redirect to={"/"} />;
  }
  if (pageLoading) {
    return <PageLoading />;
  }
  return page;
};
```

But, whenever `currentClub` for example is `null`, it doesn't even going into the `clubGuard` function, instead it directly prompt the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null` It seems that it  scans the code before entering into the function, is this a normal behavior? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because of the JSX you are passing into your function. This is evaluated before being passed to your function (as all parameters are).

```
<Link to={`/clubs/${currentClub!.id}/settings`}>  // <---- This template string is most likely the culprit
  <IoIosSettings className="icon absolute-top-right" />
</Link>
```

The exclamation mark does not do any null checks but rather tells Typescript that you **know** this cannot be null and that Typescript does not need to worry about it being null. In fact, it can still be null as no checking is done during runtime. You can read up more on that [here](https://www.triplet.fi/blog/what-is-the-use-of-exclamation-mark-operator-in-typescript/).

Simple solution would be to do a null check.

```
<Link to={`/clubs/${!!currentClub ? currentClub.id : 0}/settings`}> 
  <IoIosSettings className="icon absolute-top-right" />
</Link>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Finally, I decided to export the component :
`return clubGuard(
    currentUser,
    currentClub,
    <ClubDashboardPage currentClub={currentClub} />,
    id
);` it works well